# How to catch the add/remove of an usb token

Tags: c#, usb-drive

I just want to know how (or if) can I get the event of removing of an usb token, via GetDriveType from Win32API, or anything like that. I'm using an ePass2003 and my program is developed in C#. One solution seems to be the usage of a process with opensc in a timer but maybe there is another way to do that. Many thanks.

Comment: You should be looking for hardware notifications, not drive APIs

Comment: Thanks a lot. You are both right. I was using my phone to post it and somehow it did't alert me the possible duplication. Sorry.